# Trouble creating SQL role that can alter user mappings

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a custom role that can alter the user mapping for any database. I performed the following steos. The third step resulted in an error.

One:

```
USE master;
GO

CREATE ROLE UserMappingEditor;
```

Two:

```
USE master;
GO

GRANT ALTER ANY USER TO UserMappingEditor;
```

Three:

```
DECLARE @DatabaseName sysname;

DECLARE DatabaseCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT name
FROM sys.databases
WHERE state = 0; -- Exclude offline databases

OPEN DatabaseCursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM DatabaseCursor INTO @DatabaseName;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC('USE [' + @DatabaseName + ']; GRANT ALTER ANY USER TO UserMappingEditor;');

    FETCH NEXT FROM DatabaseCursor INTO @DatabaseName;
END

CLOSE DatabaseCursor;
DEALLOCATE DatabaseCursor;
```

I recieve this error as if the role isn't found within the databses; Whatever can or should I do?

```
Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot find the user 'UserMappingEditor', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
```

Comment: You created the UserMappingEditor role only in the master database. I think you want to include `CREATE ROLE UserMappingEditor;GRANT ALTER ANY USER TO UserMappingEditor;` after the `USE` in the dynamic script in order to setup permissions in each database.

Comment: Yeah, I hadn't creaated server wide. I created a server role with the permission in op but can't see all DBs when testing updating user mapping

Comment: I solved it. Added my role to all and works great thaks